# Creating multiple object with one response using Spring FrameWork

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

This is my first time using `Spring` to add and get data from a `database`. I have successfully established connection with my `database` and can add `Plants` with only `id` and `plantName` but now for the part that I do not understand. 
How can I create an `RowMapper` or something else that would work with a loop that would get the `Plant` and go over all `PlantParts` to get me the object I need.

I should note that `Plant` is just an Object I created to ask here to keep it cleaner and easier to answer.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Plant {
    private Long id;
    private String plantName;
    private List<PlantParts> plantParts;

    public void add(PlantParts plantPartsObj) {
        if (plantParts == null) {
            plantParts = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        plantParts.add(plantPartsObj);
    }
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PlantParts {
    private String leaves;
    private String pedicle;
    private String petals;
}
```

First I create a `Plant` object with this query:

```
INSERT INTO PLANTS (id, plantname)
  VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR sequence, ?);
```

Then I add multiple `PlantParts` with this query:

```
INSERT INTO PLANT_PARTS (id, leaves, pedicle, petals)" +
                        "  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);
```

And now I am trying to make it all into one `Plant` object, but I do not get how I can get multiple `PlantParts` with one `RowMapper`.

And this would be my code using `Spring`:

```
@Repository
public class PlantDao {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;

    @Override
    public Order getPlantById(Long id) {
        String sql = "SELECT plants.id, plants.plantName, plant_parts.id, plant_parts.leaves, plant_parts.pedicle, plant_parts.petals " +
                "FROM plants " +
                "LEFT JOIN plant_parts ON plants.id = plant_parts.id AND plants.id = ?";

        return template.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {id}, getPostRowMapper());

    }

    private RowMapper<Plant> getPostRowMapper() {
        return (rs, rowNum) -> new Plant(
                rs.getLong("id"),
                rs.getString("plantname")

                //Check if there are any PlantParts, if yes then go over
                //all of the PlantParts in a loop

        });
    }
```

Now the part that I do not understand is commented out. How can I go over all `PlantParts` in the `RowMapper`.

I would like the `RowMapper` to do something like this after setting `id and plantname`:

```
//For the first line
if(rs.getString("leaves") != null){
    plant.add(new PlantRow(rs.getString("leaves"),
            rs.getInt("pedicle"), rs.getInt("petals")));
}
while (rs.next()){
    if(rs.getString("leaves") != null){
        plant.add(new PlantRow(rs.getString("leaves"),
                rs.getInt("pedicle"), rs.getInt("petals")));
    }
}
```

I do not mind if there is another way to do it, without using `RowMapper`, I just need something that would make it work.