# Multiple objects from one ResultSet using JDBC Template with Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, resultset, spring-jdbc

This is what the `rs` gets as a result:

```
Order(id=1, orderNumber=A1, orderRows=[OrderRow(itemName=Motherboard, quantity=0, price=5), OrderRow(itemName=Cpu, quantity=5, price=0)])
```

And now I am trying to get both of the `OrderRows`:

```
private RowMapper<Order> getPostRowMapper() {
    return (rs, rowNum) -> {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
        order.setOrderNumber(rs.getString("ordernumber"));
        System.out.println("quan" + rs.getString("quantity")); // Prints 0
        System.out.println("quan" + rs.getString("price")); // Prints 5
        System.out.println("quan" + rs.getString("quantity")); // Prints 0 (should print 5)

        return order;
    };
}
```

This is how I would do it if i could do it in `a loop` if I could seperate the `OrderRows` somehow:

```
//For the first iteration
if(resultSet.getString("itemname") != null){
    order.add(new OrderRow(resultSet.getString("itemname"),
            resultSet.getInt("quantity"), resultSet.getInt("price")));
}
while (resultSet.next()){
    if(resultSet.getString("itemname") != null){
        order.add(new OrderRow(resultSet.getString("itemname"),
                resultSet.getInt("quantity"), resultSet.getInt("price")));
    }
}
```

I have two `Objects` one is `Order` and the other one is `OrderRow`. Is it possible to create multiple objects in one `RowMapper`, both `Order/OrderRow` or do I need multiple requests for that?

Or can I somehow go over all of the `OrderRows` that are in the result set and add make them into `OrderRow` objects in the iteration?

Comment: Think about how to do this using a `for loop`

Comment: Well thats what I am asking about how can I put it in a `for loop` to go over all of the `OrderRows`. `hasNext` does not work here and after that I am not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: show us the code that uses a for loop

Comment: I am sorry but I do not get what do you mean. I do not have a working code that would work with `for loop`, which is the reason I am asking

Comment: Can you try writing the code and then we can show you maybe where you are going wrong.  Not going to write the code for you.

Comment: Well I edited as to how I would do it but I really have no idea how I should get the `OrderRow` objects looping.

Comment: Looking at (and trying to understand) it appears to me the you have `one` rows returned - within that `row` you have an array, so you can use `rs.getString("ordernumber"` then `resultset.getArray("orderRows");` then you can iterate over this `Array`

Comment: I have tried getting the array that way but it throws me an error that it cannot find it. Here is more detailed question: [link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53271486/creating-multiple-object-with-one-response-using-spring-framework) . I have been at it for quite some time now and tried many solutions but none work.

Comment: How about actually posting your error and the code you are using.  Also, how did you ascertain that your `rs` is `Order(id=1, orderNumber=A1, orderRows=[OrderRow(itemName=Motherboard, quantity=0, price=5), OrderRow(itemName=Cpu, quantity=5, price=0)])`  Give clear concise information

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you posting as multiple users?

Comment: why have you abandoned this question? That's not very polite.